# Active Sendkeys in new file

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I need to use a sendkeys(% asccd) in excel (vba macro), now i have a macro that open file with path: C:// example.xlsm, select a sheet "Index", and here i need to call "%asccd", but when i try to active this workbook, the macro only write sccd inside the macro if i run step by step, and write inside one cell if i run with a command button,
I need to run this chain "n" times
How can i active the recently open file for use the sendkey %ascdd,
This is my code now:

```
Sub openclose()
Dim y As String, lRow As Long, wb_source As Workbook, wb_macro As Workbook, ws_control As Worksheet, wb_a
Dim path, sName As String
Dim x As Range

   'With Application
    '.ScreenUpdating = False
    '.DisplayAlerts = False
    '.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    'End With

Set wb_macro = ActiveWorkbook


For Each x In Range("FileList")
F = x

If x = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=F, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True)
Set wb_source = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets("Index").Select
wb_source.Activate

SendKeys "%asccd"

wb_source.Close

Next x

End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Whatever Excel feature/functionality `Alt,A,S,C,C,D` invokes, is it not possible for you to call that feature programmatically -- rather than trying to emulate manual key presses?

Comment: It is better to stick to suggestion made by chilin. however if that is not at all possible, try to use parentheses for using alt in combination with other letters. Also Try to explore adding wait and/or doevents before closing the workbook. kindly refer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement.

Comment: the main problem is that when i open one file using the macro, after this. the new open file don't recognize the command of sendkeys although i use .ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: i'm trying to emmulate clicks since vba, because i need to call a function but i don´t know where.

Comment: i have been trying wait few seconds before to start with the command, and use "call" and "Application.Run" but i don't have lucky

Comment: i use a command botton to call my macro, but when i click on the botton, the macro run but in the actual book, and don't open the file in "FileList", and when i run step by step using F8, the sendkey that active is only [%a], and the others letters are written on the next line of the macro.

Comment: @CarlosTellez I don't fully understand, but if `%asccd` calls some other code/macro/function, why not use `Application.Run` instead? It would help if you explain what `%asccd`does.

Comment: before i tried to use call " ", and application. Run, but i dont have rights for use this code,

Comment: i use a different code for this macro, and i can fixed the problem,

Comment: thanks a lot for yours suggestions !!!